# How do I use androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract$SynchronousResult in Android?

Tags: android, onactivityresult

The description of [androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract$SynchronousResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContract?hl=en#getSynchronousResult(android.content.Context,%20I)) said: "`An optional method you can implement that can be used to potentially provide a result in lieu of starting an activity.`"

Let's assume that I want to request for permissions.Generally I have to declare an ActivityResultLauncher by registerForActivityResult(contract, callback), write working logic inside the callback, and launch it in the correct time.

And to the best of my knowledge, with SynchronousResult(), I don't have to register the ActivityResultLauncher. I just need to declare an ActivityResultContract, and calling contract.SynchronousResult() will block untill the result return, i.e., user has made a desicion on the granting of permissions. So I write my code like this:

```
private boolean requestSDCardPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions contract = new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions();
        Map<String, Boolean> synchronousResult=contract.getSynchronousResult(LBL_CloudDisk_MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}).getValue();
        return synchronousResult.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) && synchronousResult.get(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    return true;
}
```

But when this code executes, a NullPointerException occurs because getValue() point to a null object, which in my opinion means SynchronousResult() didn't block and wait for the result. So how should I properly use this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per that [exact set of documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContract#getSynchronousResult(android.content.Context,%20I)):

> Returns: `SynchronousResult<O>`:  the result wrapped in a `ActivityResultContract.SynchronousResult` **or `null` if the call should proceed to start an activity.**

So it is expected that `getSynchronousResult()` will return `null` if you need to call `launch()` in order to get a valid result back. When it comes to `RequestMultiplePermissions`, [the source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:activity/activity/src/main/java/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.java;l=218) indicates that synchronous results are only returned if all permissions are already granted.

In general, **none** of the `ActivityResultContract` APIs are meant to be called directly by your app - they are all called as part of the `ActivityResultRegistry` and the regular `launch` that you should be interfacing with. Those automatically do the right thing and will internally call APIs like `getSynchronousResult()` in order to avoid launching an activity if that isn't needed. You should still be handling the results as part of the callback.